# RegEx for capturing particular digits

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

From the below logs how can i grep '951792' values  alone

```
2019 May 22 03:32:17.952296 france1v4 sh[4937]: 190522-03:32:17.951792 [mod=REC, lvl=INFO] [tid=26130] Recording A8602096210405800406L200218680503121519 size is 4145956224 bytes
2019 May 22 03:32:17.952387 france1v4 sh[4937]: 190522-03:32:17.951895 [mod=REC, lvl=INFO] [tid=26130] RecordingInfo = fffocap://0x401e
2019 May 22 03:32:17.952466 france1v4 sh[4937]: 190522-03:32:17.951934 [mod=REC, lvl=INFO] [tid=26130] recording_dvr_from_recording_info:physicalSegmentCount=10
```

I tried with java split/substring operations. but line of code is high. using regex how can i get '`951792`'  values

The output will be

```
951792
951895
951934 
075041
```

Comment: You could just split the String on the "`.`" and then split again on the first whitespace. Does it really needs to be a regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, we might want to simply use the right boundary `[mod` next to our desired digits and collect the digits in our first capturing group, maybe similar to this:

```
([0-9]+)\s\[m
```

If we wish, we can add more boundaries, such as:

```
(.+?)([0-9]+)\s\[m.+
```

[image]

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eBeay6/1)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(.+?)([0-9]+)\\s\\[m.+";
final String string = "2019 May 22 03:32:17.952296 france1v4 sh[4937]: 190522-03:32:17.951792 [mod=REC, lvl=INFO] [tid=26130] Recording A8602096210405800406L200218680503121519 size is 4145956224 bytes\n"
     + "2019 May 22 03:32:17.952387 france1v4 sh[4937]: 190522-03:32:17.951895 [mod=REC, lvl=INFO] [tid=26130] RecordingInfo = fffocap://0x401e\n"
     + "2019 May 22 03:32:17.952466 france1v4 sh[4937]: 190522-03:32:17.951934 [mod=REC, lvl=INFO] [tid=26130] recording_dvr_from_recording_info:physicalSegmentCount=10   \n";
final String subst = "\\2";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /(.+?)([0-9]+)\s\[m.+/gm;
const str = `2019 May 22 03:32:17.952296 france1v4 sh[4937]: 190522-03:32:17.951792 [mod=REC, lvl=INFO] [tid=26130] Recording A8602096210405800406L200218680503121519 size is 4145956224 bytes
2019 May 22 03:32:17.952387 france1v4 sh[4937]: 190522-03:32:17.951895 [mod=REC, lvl=INFO] [tid=26130] RecordingInfo = fffocap://0x401e
2019 May 22 03:32:17.952466 france1v4 sh[4937]: 190522-03:32:17.951934 [mod=REC, lvl=INFO] [tid=26130] recording_dvr_from_recording_info:physicalSegmentCount=10   
`;
const subst = `$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/eBeay6/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regex:

```
(?<=[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.)[0-9]+
```

don't forget to double escape the `.` (`\\.`) when you add it your java code.

**Input:**

```
2019 May 22 03:32:17.952296 france1v4 sh[4937]: 190522-03:32:17.951792 [mod=REC, lvl=INFO] [tid=26130] Recording A8602096210405800406L200218680503121519 size is 4145956224 bytes
2019 May 22 03:32:17.952387 france1v4 sh[4937]: 190522-03:32:17.951895 [mod=REC, lvl=INFO] [tid=26130] RecordingInfo = fffocap://0x401e
2019 May 22 03:32:17.952466 france1v4 sh[4937]: 190522-03:32:17.951934 [mod=REC, lvl=INFO] [tid=26130] recording_dvr_from_recording_info:physicalSegmentCount=10
```

**matches:**

```
951792
951895
951934
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/L4g8MP/1/)

For a more restrictive regex using both lookahead and lookbehind, use:

```
(?<=[0-9]\]:\s[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.)[0-9]+(?=\s\[mod=REC)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/L4g8MP/3)

**java code sample:**

```
String input = "2019 May 22 03:32:17.952296 france1v4 sh[4937]: 190522-03:32:17.951792 [mod=REC, lvl=INFO] [tid=26130] Recording A8602096210405800406L200218680503121519 size is 4145956224 bytes\n" + 
                "2019 May 22 03:32:17.952387 france1v4 sh[4937]: 190522-03:32:17.951895 [mod=REC, lvl=INFO] [tid=26130] RecordingInfo = fffocap://0x401e\n" + 
                "2019 May 22 03:32:17.952466 france1v4 sh[4937]: 190522-03:32:17.951934 [mod=REC, lvl=INFO] [tid=26130] recording_dvr_from_recording_info:physicalSegmentCount=10   ";
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\\.)[0-9]+")
.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(matches);
```

**Code output:**

```
[951792, 951895, 951934]
```

Answer (score 0):

//Iterate the loop line by line.

```
String line = "2019 May 22 03:32:17.952296 france1v4 sh[4937]: 190522-03:32:17.951792 [mod=REC, lvl=INFO] [tid=26130] Recording A8602096210405800406L200218680503121519 size is 4145956224 bytes";
      String pattern = "^.+\\.(\\d+)";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      if (m.find( )) {
          System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) ); //This would give 951792
              }else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
```

Get the regex reference here: https://regex101.com/r/8F0D4w/1